# Pulling Var Data Out Of A "If"

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, var

I'm new to programming and need help pulling data out of an if var.  I need to pull data from vars in both the if statements and combine them towards the bottom.  This is small section of my program that I'm having issues with.  This program is used to calculate after tax income using the data provided by a user.

I'm able to pull this off but only if the var is declared right above the if statement.  If I declare the var at the top and try to pull the data towards the bottom it does not work.  It states var might not have been initialized.

**Not a duplicate question.  I have search and can not find any answers that resolve this problem.  Sure I can initialize the var but I need it to pull data from the IF statement.  That was stated above.**

This is where my problem is. `combTotal += weekStTotal37k;`

```
package test; 
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double combTotal;
    double grossSalIncomeDou = 10000;
    double weekIncomeDou9k;
    double weekIncomeDou80k;
    double weekStTotal37k;

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat ("#,###.00");

        if (grossSalIncomeDou > 9325 && grossSalIncomeDou <= 37950) {
            weekIncomeDou9k = 9325 * .90;
            weekIncomeDou9k /= 52;

            weekIncomeDou80k = grossSalIncomeDou - 9325;
            weekIncomeDou80k *= .85;
            weekIncomeDou80k /= 52;

            combTotal = weekIncomeDou9k + weekIncomeDou80k;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Weekly income after taxes " + df.format (combTotal));      

        } 

        //If used to calculate income after state tax.
        if (grossSalIncomeDou <= 37110) {
            weekStTotal37k = grossSalIncomeDou * .9435;
            weekStTotal37k /= 52;

        }
            combTotal += weekStTotal37k;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Weekly income after state and fed taxes " + df.format (combTotal));
}  
}
```

Comment: Just initialise your variables with say `0.00`

Comment: I need it to pull the data from the if vars.  If I initialize it with 0s it will give me 0 as an answer.

Comment: why? you are assigning them values later aren't you?

Comment: Yes, and that's my problem.  The vars will not hold the if value.  If I assign them 0s that's all that will stick.

Comment: `if (grossSalIncomeDou <= 37110) {` **true**

Comment: so `weekStTotal37k = grossSalIncomeDou * .9435;`

Comment: so `combTotal += weekStTotal37k;` is OK

Comment: yes but I get an error stating that those two vars have not been initialized when they should already have data in them from the if statements.

Comment: **output** Weekly income after taxes 172.43
353.87019230769226

Comment: FFS - read my first comment

Comment: Umm, you're right it works now.  I will do some more digging to see where and what I was trying to wrap my head around.  It's possible I was looking at the code so long I confused myself.

Comment: Thanks Scary Wombat, I appreciate the help :)  I guess I just need to get slapped in the brain.

Comment: Have a nice day